# Equivalent form of a double integral.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, gre-exam

I am looking at the second question of this [problem set](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~wittman/reu2010/bootcamp/CalculusIII.pdf):

> The iterated integral $\int_0^1 \int_{y/2}^1 e^{x^2} dx \, dy$ can be expressed as
>
> (a) $\int_0^1 \int_0^{2x} e^{x^2} dy \, dx$
>
> (b) $\int_0^1 \int_0^{2y} e^{x^2} dy \, dx$
>
> (c) $\int_{y/2}^1 \int_0^1 e^{x^2} dy \, dx$
>
> (d) $\int_0^1 \int_0^{2y} e^{x^2} dx \, dy$
>
> (e) $\int_0^1 \int_y^1 e^{x^2} dy \, dx + \int_0^1 \int_0^y e^{x^2} dx \, dy$

The first thing I tried was to change the order of integration which gave me
$$
\int_0^1 \int_{y/2}^1 e^{x^2} dx \, dy =
\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2x}e^{x^2} dy \, dx + \int_{1/2}^1\int_0^1 e^{x^2} dy \, dx = 
e^{1/4}-1+\int_{1/2}^1e^{x^2} dx
$$

Since this didn't look like any of the available options, I tried to exclude them:

- I excluded (b),(c) and (e) as these are (non-constant) functions of $y$, in contrast to the original integral.
- (a) is wrong because it integrates the same positive function $f(x,y)=e^{x^2}$ over a proper superset of the original area of integration (with the difference of the two areas having positive measure).
- (d) is greater than the original: It integrates the same positive function over a different area, say $B$, than the original area, call it $A$. $B \setminus A$ contains the triangle $T$ defined by the points $(1,\frac{1}{2}),(1,1),(2,1)$ which is congruent to $A \setminus B$. The values of $e^{x^2}$ are greater at the points of $T$ compared to the points of $A \setminus B$. Alternatively, using wolframalpha: [original](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%20e%5E%28x%5E2%29%20dx%20dy%20for%20x%3Dy%2F2%20to%201%2C%20for%20y%3D0%20to%201) $ \approx 1.2$, [(d)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%20e%5E%28x%5E2%29%20dx%20dy%20for%20x%3D0%20to%202y%2C%20for%20y%3D0%20to%201) $\approx 3.05$

So, I have managed to exclude every option. What am I missing?

Comment: If $y$ was from $0$ to $1$ in the original then (a) would be the correct answer. Maybe there's a typo in the question.

Comment: @DylanDang: The original integral *does* involve integrating from $y=0$ to $y=1$.

Comment: Sorry I meant from 0 to 2

Comment: If $y$ goes from $0$ to $2$ than (a) is the answer. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the original region of integration $R$ is the trapezoid with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (1/2,1)$.

(a) is incorrect because the region of integration is a strict superset of $R$, containing all points in $R$ yet also including the triangle $2 > 2x > y > 1$.

(b) is notationally incorrect because the inner integral is evaluated with respect to $y$ but the upper limit of integration is a function of $y$.

(c) is also notationally incorrect since the outermost limit of integration is not a fixed interval and thus cannot evaluate to a number.

(d) is incorrect because the region of integration is a triangle with vertices $(0,0), (2,1), (0,1)$.  It is easy to see--even without computation--that the integral over the region formed by the union of the two triangular regions $1 > y > 2x > 0$ and $1/2 < x/2 < y < 1$ is much, much greater than that of the triangular region $0 < y < x/2 < 1/2$, since the integrand is constant with respect to $y$, and very rapidly increasing as a function of $x$.

(e) is notationally incorrect for the same reason that (b) is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand correctly, we are saying the same things...

Comment: Yes, we agree on our conclusions.  If the integral were to have its order of integration interchanged, the correct expression would be  $$\int_{x=0}^{1/2} \int_{y = 0}^{2x} e^{x^2} \, dy \, dx + \int_{x=1/2}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 e^{x^2} \, dy \, dx,$$ the latter term actually simplifying to a single integral over $x \in [1/2,1]$ since the integrand is constant with respect to $y$.